Kubuntu won't boot after fist startup after clean install
I'm on Kubuntu 24.04 LTS, and after installing it, I rebooted the system and now it wont boot... It just shows a black screen. I have a intel integrated video card and a NVIDIA rtx4050. I also can't enter grub since esc opens my laptops (Asus Vivobook) one-time-boot menu and shift does nothing.
I'm at a loss here...
Update: I got into grub and editing /etc/default/grub to not show splash screens during boot seemed to have helped. I'm still wondering if there is a more permanent fix possible. One that won't include not using splash screens...

https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time try the answer from cmcginty first
